# how can I install jansson 2.11-devel or above in centos7?

Tags: centos

```
 OS: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) x86_64 
 Host: VirtualBox 1.2 
 Kernel: 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 
 Packages: 638 (rpm) 
 Shell: bash 4.2.46  
 Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
 CPU: Intel i5-4200U (1) @ 2.294GHz 
 Memory: 217MiB / 1813MiB
```

I Wanna install a software (asterisk) that require

```
configure: *** Asterisk requires libjansson >= 2.11 and no system copy was found.
configure: *** Please install the 'libjansson' development package
```

And when I check my system I find that I have an older version

```
#rpm -qa | grep jansson
 jansson-2.10-1.el7.x86_64
 jansson-devel-2.10-1.el7.x86_64
```

I have spent our housers trying to get Jansson upgraded but I could not, I tried.

1. compiling from source

   I follow the steps in this [link](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.12/gettingstarted.html). And even though it told me that it's successful Installation. I didn't know how to check if it exists or not? (when I use `#rpm -qa | grep jansson` it does not show me something new ) Moreover, I want the development package, which I don't know if the above tutorial includes or not?   and if it does not include it, how to get it?

<strike>1. I try to install it from epel repository 
 I saw in this [link](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-x86_64/jansson-2.11-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) that epel dose have</strike>

2. download rpm package and install it  (see below)
   [image]

   `sudo rpm -i jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm 
   warning: jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID e55f048d: NOKEY
   error: Failed dependencies:
       jansson(x86-64) = 2.11-2.2 is needed by jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64`

   I don't understand why the dependencies same as pkg I wanna install?

to summarize my question,

1. how can I install jansson 2.11-devel or above in centos7?
2. When you compile a lib from source, how to check if it compiled successfully?
3. I don't understand why the dependencies are the same name  as pkg I wanna install

Comment: Approach the task from a different angle. Isn't `asterisk` package available? Why build it?

Comment: There are asterisk packages in Nux misc repo: http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/misc/. Probably easier if you are unfamiliar with how CentOS packaging works.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin ,  This the recommended why when you learn asterisk and get dCAA , also my company way of installing it.

Comment: @jsbillings  as what I told Danial. more I mind to learn more about linux is such process .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods you tried should be possible.
If you use the package manager (`yum`) or directly `rpm` you get an additional check on package dependencies, which is helpful in the event that something else on your system depends on the package you're trying to update.

#### Installing from source

If the compilation completed, the exit status of the command should be 0, this you can check by doing:

```
make
echo $?
```

which prints the exit status of the last command run (`make`, in this case).
If this is 0, then the compilation was successful.
If you choose to use the `make` method, `make install` should install libraries and development headers at the same time.

If you compile and install from source, using `rpm` to check if the package is installed won't be helpful (unless you build an RPM manually and subsequently install it), because the RPM DB is still only aware of the version that was installed via `rpm` (or `yum`).

**Edit 1**

The source installation method will install things to `/usr/local`, so you will have to tell the `asterisk` configure script that this is where it should look for `jansson`.

> To change the destination directory (`/usr/local` by default), use the `--prefix=DIR` argument to `./configure`. See `./configure --help` for the list of all possible configuration options.

#### Installing the local RPM file

Note that the package names aren't *exactly* the same.
You're trying to install only the `devel` package, but it's telling you that it depends on the main package.
Manually installing both RPMs (`jansson-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm` and `jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm`), *should* solve the error you reported, however, installing `jansson-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm` this way may also result in unmet/broken dependencies.
The upside is that installing this way will also let you know if other packages on your system have a dependency on `jansson-2.10` that would be broken if you were to replace the installed version.
You can even use `yum` to install the RPM, and let it handle finding the dependencies for you (if they can be resolved)

```
yum install jansson-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm
```

**Edit 2**

This presumes that you have managed to locate the two RPM files and have them locally.  If you do not have these files, and do not have a repository configured that provides them, then you will have to follow the install from source route.

Comment: `#yum install jansson-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm` is one of the first things I try actually but it does  not exist in the yum repository. so this way will not work.

Comment: I wanna get an extra bit of information, are you sure when compiling from source will provide the devel package with it? where I can see the library that I install from source on my pc and how to know its version? I will be very thankful if you help me with that

Comment: With the install from source method, it depends on how the developers designed the `install` target, but it would be extremely odd to not put everything that would be in the `-devel` package (the headers and possibly library soname links) into the target location.
You can check what would be done by doing `make -n install`, which will print the steps that would be taken, but not actually execute them.

Comment: oh I though  that installing local packages only can be done with rpm like 
`rpm -i jansson-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm jansson-devel-2.11-2.2.x86_64.rpm` not with yum install

Comment: Indeed, you can also use `yum` to install local RPM packages, and it has the added benefit of being able to search for and resolve dependencies in the repositories you have configured for your system.  See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876875/how-to-make-rpm-auto-install-dependencies) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89422/resolve-dependencies-installing-rpm-packages) for more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific need of building (e.g *compiling*) Asterisk 16 in CentOS 7, we have the following mismatch:

- Asterisk 16 requires libjansson version >= 2.11.
- CentOS 7 repositories provide [libjansson-devel version 2.10](https://pkgs.org/download/jansson-devel).

A direct way to solve that is to use the *bundled* libjansson library that comes with the Asterisk sources, with a command like this one:

```
./configure --with-jansson-bundled
```

With that, there is no need to install RPM packages for libjansson.

I pressume, but have not verified, the following:

- The same applies to newer Asterisk versions, like 18 or 20.
- The same applies to old Ubuntu versions, like 16.04.

The bundled version of Jansson library seems to be [regularly updated in the releases of different Asterisk versions](https://www.asterisk.org/pjsip-2-12-now-in-asterisk/).